# Is there a Weierstrass product for the Harmonic number?

Tags: complex-analysis

I’m just learning.  For all complex values except the negative integers, the harmonic number is given by

$$H_x = x\sum_{k=1}^\infty \frac{1}{k(x+k)}$$

$H_0=0$ and there are infinitely many roots at negative values.

Is this an entire function?  If so, could we factor the harmonic number as a Weierstrass product?  I could not find any sources on the harmonic number as a product.

**Added:** It seems that $\frac{H_x}{x!}$ should admit a product form, right?

Comment: $H_x$ has a simple pole at each negative integer.

Comment: Oh so it’s not entire. Thank you very much

Comment: Relevant:  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Digamma_function#Relation_to_harmonic_numbers and https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Digamma_function#Infinite_product_representation